# Angular routing takes to home page on manual refresh or directly typing url

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular-routing

I have angular app being served by node.js server. Upon manual refresh or directly typing url /xyz or /abc, as shown in example below.I see it to be directed to home page.

Ex:I click on naviagtion button(xyz and abc) it takes me to  https://mywebsite/xyz and https://mywebsite/abc correspondingly. I see only /xyz or /abc appended to  https://mywebsite.

I am angular in production, I have this served as static file. I will show some code snippet.
Please I authenticate users based on JWT, it is stored in localStorage

**app-routing**

```
..I have imported those components here..
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent , canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  //{ path: '', component: SigninComponent,
    children: [ 
      { path: '', component: xyz },
      { path: 'xyz', component: xyz },
      { path: 'abc', component: abc },
    ]}
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes

    )
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [],
})
export class RoutingModule { }
```

**app.js**

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/client')));

app.get('/',function(req,res){  
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/index.html'));
}); 
    let index = path.join(__dirname, '../../client/index.html');
    res.sendFile(index);
```

I expected upon redirecting to index.html to take me to app-routing. So, that I make manual refresh in  https://mywebsite/abc  I remain in https://mywebsite/abc  itself and not to home page.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Portal</title>
    <base href="/">
    <app-root>

        </app-root>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your home component is having the [AuthGuard], try removing the AuthGurad and check.

Comment: I removed AuthGuard and checked, its the same issue. The AuthGuard is returning true as it persist data in local storage

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the page that you are currently on is automatically getting redirected on refresh.

To fix this you need to enable hash routing in the router like so:

```
imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {useHash: true})
  ],
```

This will make angular not redirect to base url on refresh